# Is it posible in dataweaver 1.0 decapitalise first letter in key name, not value?

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule-component, mule-esb

I have such input:

```
{
 Abc: "1",
 BcD: "2",
 ...
 klm: "3",
 ZXC: "4"
}
```

I want to get output after transform like this:

```
{
 abc: "1",
 bcD: "2",
 ...
 klm: "3",
 zXC: "4"
}
```

How I can do that?
Have been tried like that:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
  ($$) replace /^([A-Z])/ with lower $$[1] : $
}
```

but getting error:

> There is no variable named '$$'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

**Input**

```
{
 "Abc": "1",
 "BcD": "2",
 "klm": "3",
 "ZXC": "4"
}
```

**Script**

```
%dw 1.0
%input payload application/json
%output application/json
---
payload mapObject {
  (lower ($$)[0] ++ (($$)[1 to -1])):$
}
```

**Output**

```
{
  "abc": "1",
  "bcD": "2",
  "klm": "3",
  "zXC": "4"
}
```

Comment: I forgot about the lower operator in DW 1.0. This is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use mapObject to change the keys. Note that `$$` only makes sense in the context of some operators. You need to put the entire key expression between parenthesis. I used pattern matching instead.

Example:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
%function lowerFirst(s)
    s[0] match {
        'A' -> 'a' ++ s[1..-1],
        'B' -> 'b' ++ s[1..-1],
        // add other letters mapping       
        default -> s
    }
     
---
payload mapObject (lowerFirst($$)): $
```

Note that you need to complete the letters mapping in the function.